# Get child div to overflow its parent div on the right

Tags: css, html

The parent div `header` in this case is extending on the right and in spite of using `max-width`.

It may be something simple I've overlooked but I've tried `padding` and it just expands out further.

The site is here:
http://deathproofpr.spilt.com.au/

There is an additional problem in that ie7 doesn't show the menu image at all, but I know there is a hack for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `min-width: 880px`. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want overlap effect: the width of your white "main" bg is 860px and you have a negative -10px margin on the #menuimage so I'm guessing you do and that's the question, to get it to work on both sides:

**`#header`:  remove the following**

```
 display: table;
 height: 150px;
 max-width: 860px;
 overflow: hidden;
```

**`#header`: change**

```
  width: 860px;
```